# How to build artifacts conditionally based on project version using gradle?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

Hi I hava a project named A of three modules(core, mobile web) with below structure:

```
A
   --settings.gradle
   --build.gradle
   --core
     --build.gradle
   --web
      --build.gradle
   --mobile
      --build.gradle
```

My settings.gradle is like:

```
include 'core'
include 'web'
include 'mobile'
```

There are different versions already, and until from version 2.0 we supply the mobile module, and before that we don't want to build "mobile" module. Now I have 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 2.1 versions, and we test and check compilations before each code commit. We did this this way:

```
VERSIONS=( "1.0" "1.1" "1.2" "2.0" "2.1 )
for version in "${VERSIONS[@]}"; do (gradle -PspringBootVersion=${version} clean install uploadArchives); done
```

This way in versions before 2.0, it will still build "mobile" module, and this of course will fail. My question is how to check and build the project conditionally? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include 'core'
include 'web'

if("${springBootVersion}" ==~ /2\.[0-9]) {
    include include 'mobile'
}
```

It's really simple, I only modify the settings.gradle above way, Then I got the right result.